# Flutter build Xcode project issue:Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both

Tags: flutter, jenkins-pipeline, xcodebuild

I have set up the environment of Flutter,then i executed command **flutter build ios** in terminal,the building is successful!But building with Jenkins is failed,The error infomations as follows:
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 68645BWR55
14:21:18  Running pod install...                                           2,468ms
14:22:05  Running Xcode build...
14:22:05  Xcode build done.                                           43.4s
14:22:05  Failed to build iOS app
14:22:05  Error output from Xcode build:
14:22:05  ↳
14:22:05      objc[7522]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x20e47ab90) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1079602c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
14:22:05      objc[7522]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x20e47abe0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107960318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
14:22:05      ** BUILD FAILED **